# Missing sql_plugin.h file in MySQL 5.7 installation

Tags: mysql

I was following the plugin-writing tutorial at this page:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/writing-daemon-plugins.html

When I created the project for the example in Visual Studio, the build failed because the header file sql_plugin.h is missing from the MySQL installation. My MySQL installation is 5.7.18, but the file in question is not present.

Is there a mismatch between the documentation and the release, or am I making a mistake somewhere else?

I am on Windows 10 (x64), using Visual Studio 2017. I have configured my Visual Studio installation with the include and library paths necessary for fetching the header and the .lib files.

Also: If you are familiar with the MySQL ecosystem, and have any advice for someone who is new to the topic of developing for MySQL, your thoughts are welcome.

Comment: You have to download the headers independent. They should be in the source package

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Thank you so much, I'll go ahead and do that. But how would a newbie know that? I scanned most of the documentation, and didn't come across that requirement.

Comment: Bin packages, separate header packages and source code packages are pretty much the standard method in open source projects. So I think nobody thought about documenting this explicit.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen OK, thank you again.